# How to create JS library by scala-js

Tags: javascript, scala, sbt, scala.js

How can I create a JS library in scala-js? I am using standard Play/Scala server + scala-js client with shared objects. I want my library to be on URI /api/mylib.js. 
I don't know how make scala-js client project without main method. Also how to generate scala-js code to the specific URL I need.

Comment: The particular URL at which you serve your .js file depends on your web server (Play!), not on Scala.js itself. This should be asked as a separate SO question with the `playframework` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write a JS library, you need to [*export* the public API to JavaScript](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html).

You will also likely want to disable the generation of the "launcher", which looks for a `JSApp` in your classpath and calls its main method. Otherwise `fastOptJS` will complain that it cannot find any `JSApp`. You can do this with the following sbt setting:

```
persistLauncher := false
```

Edit: See also the blog post [How to make an idiomatic Javascript library with Scala.js](http://pavkin.ru/how-to-make-an-idiomatic-javascript-library-with-scala-js/)